# PCL Point Feature Histograms - binning

Tags: histogram, point-cloud-library, feature-extraction, feature-selection

The binning process, which is part of the point feature histogram estimation, results in `b^3` bins if only the three angular features (alpha, phi, theta) are used, where b is the number of bins.

Why is it `b^3` and not `b * 3`?

Let's say we consider alpha.
The feature value range is subdivided into b intervals. You iterate over all neighbors of the query point and count the amount of alpha values which lie in one interval. So you have b bins for alpha. When you repeat this for the other two features, you get `3 * b` bins.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, I'll first explain it in 2D, i.e. with two angular features. In that case, you would have b^2 bins, not b*2.

The feature space is divided into a regular grid. Features are binned according to their position in the 2D (or 3D) space, not independently along each dimension. See the following example with two feature dimensions and b=4, where the feature is binned into the cell marked with `#`:

```
^ phi
|
+-+-+-+-+
| | | | |
+-+-+-+-+
| | | | |
+-+-+-+-+
| | | |#|
+-+-+-+-+
| | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-> alpha
```

The feature is binned into the cell where alpha is in a given interval AND phi in another interval. The key difference to your understanding is that the dimensions are **not** treated independently. Each cell specifies an interval on all the dimensions, not a single one.
(This would work the same way in 3D, only that you would have another dimension for theta and a 3D grid instead of a 2D one.)

This way of binning results in b^2 bins for the 2D case, since each interval in the `alpha` dimension is combined with ALL intervals in the `phi` dimension, resulting in a squaring of the number, not a doubling. Add another dimension, and you get the cubing instead of the tripling, as in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :).